# None of my Win Forms buttons work

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.5, vb.net-2010

I have a windows form which connects to a SQL Server though a dataset. The form was working fine since my last compile. All of a sudden, none of my buttons work! The data is loaded on the form, all the tabs work fine, drop down boxes work fine, but the buttons are literally unresponsive to any clicks. I added a test button and I get the same results. I can visually see the button getting clicked but no events. Any ideas?

Comment: @Davlog I'm not sure which part of the code to show. I have 6k lines of code.

Comment: Do your button click events still have Handles plus your control names after them?

Comment: @MarkHall Yes, this is a button I have just added on the form and it doesn't work:   Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        MsgBox("hello")
    End Sub

Comment: Try cleaning then rebuilding your project

Comment: @MarkHall I just did that, still nothing. I'm running VS as admin as well.

Comment: The next step would be to restart VS, then if that doesn't work try restarting windows. Try setting breakpoints in your Form_Load and/or Form Constructor.

Comment: I restarted the VS, my PC but still nothing

Comment: Sometimes my VS Project was a little buggy so I copied the whole code (not the files) to a complete new project. Still haven't found out why that happened but it worked.

Comment: Glad  you got it figured.. That was the next thing I was going to suggest :)

Comment: @MarkHall I didn't. Davlog did. I'm still in the same situation. I load a different form on the load event of my main form and the buttons are clickable and work. Is there any setting which disables the buttons on the form to work?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, First make a backup of your program folder, then delete the program options file (the file in your program directory with "yourProgramName.suo") and see if that works. It will be recreated when you open your project again.  Sorry, I had assumed that it was you that responded, I should have read the username a little more closely.

Comment: @MarkHall I have done that. The method that helped me to find the solution was to put the break points. I was calling the method 'InitializeComponent' when a DataGridView was getting loaded a cell was getting selected. After putting the breakpoints it helped me to find the solution. If you want me to mark the answer as 'answered' please just put your recommendations together and I will do so. Many thanks.

Comment: @nectarines That's fine the most important thing is that you got it resolved. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to save multiple copies of your programs in more than one place(including other storage forms). That will save you a bunch in a hard drive crash. Save to them often. When your solutions are working after cleaning and rebuilding this will be the ultimate backup.

Answer (score 0):

In the VB editor, main menu go: Build-->Configuration Manager, and make sure that "Debug" is the option for Active Solution Configuration and Project Context.  It can't be "Release" to run the validity check below.  (none of these instructions will change your code, but rather will simply confirm it is executing ok).

Next, in your Form, double click on a button during editing (not run-time), and once inside the code for a button, click on the far left vertical gray-colored column (1/4" wide) on a line with a field or variable that should get filled (make sure that a maroon-colored bullet appears in the gray column for that specific line).  Run the code and then click on this button, and if the code is working in this button, execution should stop on this line and the line should be highlighted in yellow.  If this doesn't happen, your code is not executing.